# Helm deployment without the right to list secrets

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy an application using Helm from an Azure DevOps pipeline to a private Kubernetes cluster. I've setup a rolebinding that does not include listing of secrets or getting them (it does have `create`, `update` , `patch` and `delete` on secrets to deploy them). I'd like to keep the rolebindings for this as tight as possible.

But in the current deployment an error occurs:

```
query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:my-service-account" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "my-namespace"
```

Helm is (probably) trying to read the sh.helm.release.* secrets to determine the current state of the application.

Obviously, I could just add the `list` and `get` for secrets in the role, but I'd rather not, because that would also grant access to other secrets.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to deploy a helm chart without granting `list` (and probably `get`) for secrets?
2. What is exactly in these secrets? I've examining them, but it's binary. I think the data used to be in a normal ConfigMap. Is it wise / possible to go back to using ConfigMaps for this data?

Thanks for any help.

Q.

Comment: By default Helm stores most of its state in Secrets, but you can configure a different [storage backend](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends).  Does setting `HELM_DRIVER=configmap` work?  (Anything you've already installed will probably be "lost" if you do this.)

Comment: (I also don't know whether Helm needs "list" or "get" permissions to be able to install charts that happen to create Secrets.)

Comment: @David Maze: I'm not installing any secrets with Helm. This is about the secrets Helm creates itself. I could probably put the state in a ConfigMap, but I'd like to know what's in the state before I do that. Is there anything sensitive in that state?

Comment: It has a complete copy of the values with which the chart was deployed.  Depending on the specific charts, that may or may not include things like passwords.